Does Windows "Reset this PC" wipes user profiles and apps on other drives?
I've searched for other questions related to "Reset this PC" but didn't found an answer for my specific case.
Context:
My Windows install is 12 years old (Win10 upgraded from a Win7) and I've changed the hardware a year ago (motherboard, processor, gpu). I've messed up a lot in the registry and env variables (for software development).
So now my Windows system is quite unstable and I want to make a clean install (even though I know it will take me an entire week to setup and reinstall all my apps).
Because of disk space issues a while ago, I've moved my Users folder on another drive (so my Download, Documents, Musics, etc. are not on the system drive).
I've moved my pagefile.sys on another drive too.
Also, there are Program Files and Program Files (x86) on several drives, since I've installed apps on multiple drives (for example I have a drive with all my games, a drive with the softwares for work, etc.).
There are also some apps installed in the Users directory (for example in %LocalAppData%\Programs for Visual Studio Code)
Questions:
When doing a "Reset this PC" (using either "Keep my files" or "Remove Everything") on the system drive only, what is really kept or removed?

Will user profiles on another drive be wiped? (I assume it will be untouched for both cases?)
Will apps on other drives be wiped like the ones on the system drive? (I think not? Or maybe Windows considers all installed apps whereever they are?)
Will apps installed in user profiles be kept (even when located in the system drive)?

Other related questions:

If apps are not removed, I assume they will not run properly because the registry keys have been removed? Or does it just mean that Windows is not aware of them? (because the apps will re-create the registry keys they use if not present).
Do I need to move back the pagefile.sys on system drive before the reset? or is it safe to keep it on another drive during the reset?


Not an answer, but getting a new drive and installing fresh onto that is the safest option. You get a new install, your original data is safe, reinstalling applications is a pain but you'd probably have to do it with the reset anyway.

@NickSlash Yeah, I'm prepared to reinstall all apps because I think I'll upgrade to Win11 after the reset, so I can install apps for Win11 directly. Buying a new drive to install a fresh Win without resetting previous is a possible solution for me, I think. Didn't expected to extend my storage but why not :)



Will user profiles on another drive be wiped?
Will apps on other drives be wiped like the ones on the system drive?
Will apps installed in user profiles be kept (even when located in the system drive)?


Reset this PC only modifies the system partition. You should of course, always have a backup of any critical files, in the event of a disk failure. You will have to reinstall any software that is installed.

Do I need to move back the pagefile.sys on system drive before the reset?

The page file will be deleted during the process of reinstalling Windows.

You should of course, always have a backup of any critical files
It's not clear with your answer: do I need to backup any files on other drives? could a reset can make disk failure on other drives?
The page file will be deleted during the process of reinstalling Windows.
Even on another drive? You say the reset only modifies the system partition. I know the installation after the wipe will create a new pagefile on the system drive, but my concern is about before, during the wipe.

I have learned that, I need to warn people to perform a backup, because when I didn't in the past they put their data loss on my instructions. Don't worry about the page file. The page file won't even be used during the installation process. The page file will be deleted because, the page file, is not retained during the installation process.

Okay, I understand, but do you suggest to backup only system drive, or all drives? (in case where apps and user profiles are also on other drives). Also your answer doesn't really answer my original questions: what happens exactly during a reset to apps and user profiles located on other drives?

Your critical files.  As I explained in my answer, you will have to reinstall your applications, since they are installed on another drive, once Windows is reinstalled it will know nothing about them.

As Ramhound states, make a backup. Safest is to make complete drive images for all drives. If something goes wrong, it allows return to conditions as they were before. Drive images also allow complete recovery should a drive die, too -- and SSD, in particular, seem to fail more completely, without warning, than HDD.

Even if your profile wasn't on another volume or Program Files were not located on another drive, you would still have to reinstall your applications.  The only difference is those folders on another partition won't touched when Windows is reinstalled.
